# How to check if a variable is double or string

Tags: java

Okay this is really basic knowledge I just started coding. Anyways I made a variable;

```
double radius
```

and I want an if condition to do this;

```
if (radius != double) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number."); }
```

So the thing is I don't know the code for Java to check if radius is NOT a double. For example a string. The one I entered is obviously wrong.
Can anyone tell me the correct one?

Comment: this is to late, since your variable is declared to be a (primitive) double it cannot hold a String or anything else.

Comment: Try doing some research on the double.Parse() and double.TryParse() methods.

Comment: The best way is to read the code where you declared what it was.

Comment: If you are trying to parse a string as a double, then [`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) will throw an exception (which you can catch) if the string can't be parsed.

Comment: `radius` is a double 100% of the time.  How did you put something into `radius`?  That's where something might happen that you need to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the value and catch the exception for example, may be you can try like this

```
 try{
       Double.valueOf("asdasd");
   }
   catch (Exception ex){
       System.out.println("Not a valid double value");
   }
```

it returns `Not a valid double value`

Wrapper class `Double` could be helpful though. You can do something like this:

```
 try{
       if(radius instanceof  Double)
            System.out.println(radius);
   }
   catch (Exception ex){
       System.out.println("error");
   }
```

radius has to be declared as `Double`.

PS: `instanceof` won't work with `double`, it is a primitive datatype.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double radius;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Input Radius:");
    try {
        inputt = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
    }
}
```

Only break the while loop if user inputs a number/double.